# Jquery hiding child tabs and displaying on first click

Tags: jquery, css, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using jQuery Tools to create a series of tabs within tabs (nested tabs). You can see a demo of the effect here (2nd demo): http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/multiple-tabs.htm

I am trying to only show the first series of tabs when you load the page, and then one you click on a tab, it loads as normal.

Currently, I am using jquery to achieve this effect but it is NO WAY ideal. Here is my code:

```
//set the 2nd row of tabs to be invisible (display none doesnt work)
$(".pane:first").css("opacity","0");

//remove the class current, so the first tab doesnt show it's current css state
$("ul.tabs li a.current").removeClass("current");

//when any tab is clicked
$("ul.tabs a").click(function(){

    //animate the 2nd row of tabs back to full opacity
    $(".pane:first").animate({
              "opacity":"1"
        }, 1000);
    });
```

PROBLEM ONE: I want this to only work on the FIRST time `ul.tabs a` is clicked. After the opacity is at 1, I dont need to run this script every time `ul.tabs a` is clicked

PROBLEM TWO: Because I am simply setting the opacity to 0, the elements are still loaded into the DOM and take up space. I cannot use display:none, because the tab js script will ignore it.

This works...but I know this is not the best way to go about this. Any ideas on how I can optimize this code, or go about this completely differently?

THANKS!

Comment: Have you tried [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/)? You can do lot of customizations. See the documentation on the bottom of the page.

Comment: I have not - i havn't seen the UI plugin with nested tabs....Is that done fairly easily? Still, this isn't an issue of which UI to choose, but rather how to fix this existing problem.

Comment: the right way of doing this is to create a custom effect similar to this link:  http://sdevgame.wordpress.com/2011/02/04/custom-jquery-tools-tab-transitions/

Answer (score 0):

Using [.one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) will fix your first problem.  jQuery UI does have a pretty easy to use Tabs function that works great with nested tabs.  It might fix problem 2 (allowing you to set display:none).

```
$("#foo").one("click", function() {
  alert("This will be displayed only once.");
});
```

ETA: Just to make this a bit easier

```
$("ul.tabs a").one("click", function(){

    //animate the 2nd row of tabs back to full opacity
    $(".pane:first").animate({
              "opacity":"1"
        }, 1000);
    });
```

Comment: for some reason the .one method does not work here. I received the alert on every single click. I actually tried this before and gave up because the one method wasnt working with this set of tabs. I will give the UI plugin a shot.

Comment: If .one isn't working, try the longhand way:
$("#foo").bind("click", function( event ) {
  alert("This will be displayed only once.");
  $(this).unbind( event );
});

Comment: Oh wait, I think I see.  .one will bind to each item you've got selected, which means for each 'ul.tabs a', it will allow a single click.  If you've got 5 tabs up top, it will allow a click on each one once.  Maybe bind to the whole menu instead of a tab?

Comment: ahh thats a good idea, I will give that a try and let you know